# Bug when combining Dataset with a scoping construct and Map

Tags: bugs, scoping, dataset, map, pure-function

The following fails in v11:

```
data = Dataset@<|"A" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>, "B" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>, "C" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>|>
Map[With[{num = "A"}, #[[num]]] &, data]
```

Returning a `Failure` expression about `num` not being a valid specification, as if it didn't get evaluated. On the other hand this works (by bypassing `num`):

```
Map[With[{num = "A"}, #[["A"]]] &, data]
```

I can confirm that this is a problem on at least PC and Mac. This also works fine when it's just an `Association` and not a `Dataset`.

Comment: I don't know if this should be considered a bug or a design limitation of the overloading of `Part` to work in a peculiar way with Datasets.  Typically one would not want the entire `Function` (body) to be evaluated before the actual application as that could have undesired side-effects.  However without that evaluation `num` *is not* a valid specification.  Consider another example without `With` that throws the same error:  
    `Map[(num = "A"; #[[num]]) &, data]`  Hopefully one of the developers see this and either explains this as a design trade-off or a bug.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `MapAt` doesn't have this limitation, hence I think we have a bug here (see my answer).

Comment: @Alexey Thank you for looking deeper.  I only had time for a comment before.  I shall revise my conjecture: this may be part of an optimization routine for `Map` as applied to `Dataset`, analogous to but separate from compilation for packable data.  In such cases `Function` may be processed uniquely which could explain why it appears in the simple example I gave, but not for `f[d_] := (num = "A"; d[[num]])`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Very possible, but such an optimization shouldn't significantly alter the behavior of basic functions, so it should be a bug anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"
> ```

```
data = Dataset@<|"A" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>, "B" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>, "C" -> <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 4|>|>
```

> [image: dataset]

Simplified example [provided by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/bug-when-combining-dataset-with-a-scoping-construct-and-map#comment339573_125422) produces the error:

```
Clear[num]
(num = "A"; #[[num]]) & /@ data
num
```

> [image: error message]
>
> ```
> num
> ```

Without `Map` it works as expected:

```
Clear[num]
(num = "A"; #[[num]]) &@data
num
```

> [image: dataset]
>
> ```
> "A"
> ```

With usual functions and `Map` it is fine too:

```
Clear[num, f]
f[d_] := (num = "A"; d[[num]]);
f /@ data
```

> [image: dataset]

```
Clear[num, f]
f[d_] := With[{num = "A"}, d[[num]]];
f /@ data
```

> [image: dataset]

These convince me that the error is not in `Part` being overloaded for `Dataset` as [suspected by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/bug-when-combining-dataset-with-a-scoping-construct-and-map#comment339573_125422).

Let us try `MapAt`:

```
Clear[num]
MapAt[(num = "A"; #[[num]]) &, data, 1]
num
```

> [image: dataset]
>
> ```
> "A"
> ```

```
Clear[num]
MapAt[(num = "A"; #[[num]]) &, data, {{1}, {2}, {3}}]
```

> [image: dataset]

We see that `MapAt` works as expected (although there is a bug in typesetting - but that is a different story which is not related to `MapAt`).

The above examples convince me that the error is indeed a bug in `Dataset` when a pure function with part extraction is `Map`ped over it.

Comment: But this works: `(num = "A"; hello[#, num]) & /@ data)` ... So `Part` is somehow **also** responsible for the problem. Or did I understand something wrong ?

Comment: @SquareOne Yes, `Part` is responsible as well as `Map` and `Function`. Corrected my answer.